# Issue faced on including inappBrowser plugin in Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using Cordova 3.6 version. I am trying to use inappBrowser plugin in my application. But I keep 
getting these errors on running the app.

I had imported the inappbrowser plugin from the command line, by following the steps mentioned on the following site:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Just for your reference, I have pasted the log errors below:

```
11-07 17:36:15.565: W/ResourceType(9928): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928): Uncaught exception from plugin
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1884)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$5.run(InAppBrowser.java:503)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4763)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.showWebPage(InAppBrowser.java:657)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$1.run(InAppBrowser.java:152)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4763)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.execute(InAppBrowser.java:113)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:103)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:84)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:147)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.promptOnJsPrompt(CordovaBridge.java:129)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:192)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:887)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
11-07 17:36:15.588: E/PluginManager(9928):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 17:36:15.752: I/GATE(9928): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-07 17:37:10.385: I/CordovaLog(10665): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
11-07 17:37:10.385: D/CordovaActivity(10665): CordovaActivity.init()
11-07 17:37:10.393: I/dalvikvm(10665): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.enableRemoteDebugging
11-07 17:37:10.393: W/dalvikvm(10665): VFY: unable to resolve static method 300: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled (Z)V
```

Let me know if the information provided is clear enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround in this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6407):

> The manual workaround for this is to copy over the drawable resources from the res directory of the plugin to the res directory of your application. These are the forward/back/cancel icons for InAppBrowser. [>>](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6407?focusedCommentId=14084714&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14084714)